# Android Facebook login callback

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

i'm programming a simple facebook login for my android app, i've just configured sdk and added fb login button, i'm trying to display in logcat facebook response but it seems as if callback function is not triggered.

This is my onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    Log.e("", String.valueOf(loginResult));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
    });
}
```

Anyone can help me? Thank's

Comment: Maybe you're getting an error, that you're ignoring

Comment: Android studio isn't giving me any error, the app is not crashing and in log there's no error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with facebook app settings
1. Package Name
2. Development key hash

Answer (score 0):

Read this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4). There's a complete example that you can just copy and paste.